# Weblogic 12c kerberos application

Tags: kerberos, cas, weblogic12c, jaas, gssapi

I have written an application which extends CAS 3.5.3

CAS supports Kerberos protocol for authentication. So when I deploy this application on tomcat/jboss etc, I am able to login to my application via Kerberos. I have done settings on jboss. However wasn't able to find any concrete documentation for weblogic.
The documents I have found is
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/idm/weblogic-sso-kerberos-1619890.html - but this seems to be for securing the Weblogic console and now for my application.

When I try to login, getting the following error :-

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Configuration was registered that can handle the configuration named jcifs.spnego.accept
        at com.bea.common.security.jdkutils.JAASConfiguration.getAppConfigurationEntry(JAASConfiguration.java:130)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:259)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.(LoginContext.java:425)
        ... 144 more

Comment: That link is the correct (and best that I've seen) documentation for configuring WebLogic with Kerberos for applications, not just the console. However, even with the documentation getting to it work is still tricky.

Comment: okay thanks, will keep trying on this path then. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took quiet a long time to get this right, the steps are pretty simple. If you application is using jaas and you already have Kerberos authentication code (cas) in your webapp, the following solved my issue :-

1)Keep your jaas file inside /WEB-INF/classes dir.
2) pass this as an java opt, in  startweblogic.cmd

set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Djava.security.auth.login.config=\WEB-INF\classes\jaas.conf

reboot the server and try to login.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following property to JAVA_OPTIONS in your domains\your_domain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd file, or alternatively set it in weblogic console at Environment/Servers/Control/your_domain/Server Start/Arguments.

-DUseSunHttpHandler=true